# Linux CentOS ntpd doesnt work, time allways +2 hours

Tags: linux

Hello i have installed ntp service, but my time is +2 hours, in 
**/etc/ntp.conf** 
i have ntp server from i want to sync, 
**/etc/init.d/ntpd status is running**.. when i did 
`ntpdate ntp.anyserver.tld` time is synchronised and `date` command show right date, 
my **timezone** (date +%Z) **is right** too.. when i set a right date and stop ntpd the time also change +2 hours.. (but not immediately it takes time) where is the problem ?? thank you
ps: im using **CentOS release 5.8** and its **VPS** server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set your HWClock to be taken as GMT instead of local time. Set your linux to read your HWClock as local time and you probably will be good

Comment: if this is really the issue, i suggest to do it the other way round and set the HWClock to use UTC if possible. nobody would voluntarily store local times.

Comment: thank you, i cant access hwclock so i did some changes in ntpd.conf and if it will does not work i will add ntpdate to hourly cron :-)